# How insert array value in each index of another array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am having two arrays, in that i need to insert the each index of last key and value of another array keys, values in php. My sample arrays are given below. I am using codeigniter framework.

First array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [customer_name] => Cash
            [ordernumber] => 6452424
            [product_name] => Bacardi Rum
            [quantity] => 1
            [unit_price] => 25.00
            [inv_discount] => 0.00
            [salesman_id] => 25,27
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [customer_name] => Cash
            [ordernumber] => 6452424
            [product_name] => Baileys
            [quantity] => 1
            [unit_price] => 15.00
            [inv_discount] => 0.00
            [salesman_id] => 28,29
        )

)
```

Second array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 140140,150150
    [1] => 151151,05180518
)
```

And i need the o/p :

```
Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [customer_name] => Cash
                [ordernumber] => 6452424
                [product_name] => Bacardi Rum
                [quantity] => 1
                [unit_price] => 25.00
                [inv_discount] => 0.00
                [salesman_id] => 25,27
                [salesman] => 140140,150150
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [customer_name] => Cash
                [ordernumber] => 6452424
                [product_name] => Baileys
                [quantity] => 1
                [unit_price] => 15.00
                [inv_discount] => 0.00
                [salesman_id] => 28,29
                [salesman] => 151151,05180518
            )

    )
```

Can any one help me, give some ideas to solve this.

Comment: Do a loop and use the key to identify element in the other array.

Comment: i did loop but i cant get exact solution. Again i'm checking and let you know

Comment: Then add it with your question.

Comment: i checked my loop was wrong. Now i got the solution. Thank you guys ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you have an array of objects (**stdClass type**) and one other array only. Answering your question you just have to do the code as shown below.

```
foreach ($secondArray as $key => $value) {
    $firstArray[$key]->salesman = $value;
}
```

or

```
foreach ($firstArray as $key => $object) {
    $object->salesman = $firstArray[$key];
}
```

Comment: @JaganAkash I'm happy to help you!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arrA as $key=>$val){
   $arrA[$key]['salesman'] = $arrB[$key];
}
```

Comment: he has 2 arrays, I have looped through 1st array and added in its each sub array an item from second array where both array's indexes are same

Comment: The reason for the comment above is your answer was flagged for review (and put in the low quality posts list) because on SO code only answers are discouraged. I reviewed your answer from the review queue and instead of voting to delete it I made my comment and skipped the vote using the skip button.

Comment: thank you, i will be adding some text along with code to avoid this in future

Answer (score 0):

As long as both arrays will be same size, `array_map` will be suitable:

```
$resultArray = array_map(function ($rowA, $rowB) {
    $rowA->salesman = $rowB;
    return $rowA;
}, $firstArray, $secondArray);
```